# What is db in mongodb CLI?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I use a simple query on a collection say `testdb` the query looks like db.testdb.find()

I want to know what is `db` in the above query?

I know its  but why always do we need to use `db` in all the queries that we use in mongodb?

I am a beginner and would like to know why do we do so?

Thanks,

Zingo

Comment: Did you read the MongoDB tutorial? It explains that!

Comment: Why did this question get an upvote? Seroiusly?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did go through the tutorial I found its means <database> but I was not aware why its db i mean cant it have some other reference? So after reading the following answer I did understand why.

Comment: So your asking why its called db? I dunno, the pereson felt a bit iffy that day?

Comment: @Sammaye the question is not why its called db the question was what is db? and gustavohenke did answer my question and I understood that there are other shell variables as well.

Comment: But you just said you found a tutorial that said it was the database but you was not aware why it was db instread of say, dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db` is a shell variable which points to the current selected database (d'oh!). It holds common operations for the db, like help, collections, management, etc.

You're stranging this probably because you haven't used other shell variables yet, but they exist:

- `sh`: For when you're in a sharded environment.
- `rs`: For when you're in a replica set scenario.
- `it`: Result of the last line evaluated, used to further iterations.

So, basically, the `db` var exist for separating things in the shell. If you know client JavaScript - think of using global variables for everything. It's bad! The same applies to the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 1):

`db` is a variable which represents current database. If you don't like to repeat `db.testdb` on every query to your collection, then you can store `db.testdb` in separate variable:

```
> var testdb = db.testdb
> testdb.find()
> testdb.findOne()
```

Comment: Woww that's something new.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`db` is a reference to the current database
`db.testdb` is a reference to the collection `testdb` in the current database

Answer (score 0):

db is the variable assigned to the current db object. It's changed with a "use [dbname]" call. 
It's a useful abstraction to allow for, e.g. easier scripting/API development. 
You can rely upon writing scripts with the db call and allow another piece of code to handle ensuring it's the right instance.

Comment: Thanks
That as well is new for me.
Zingo